# CardView for Android 9.0 has space black blank, how to remove the black space

Tags: android, kotlin

CardView for Android has black spaces, how to remove it. i need help.
this is java or android problem.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QryIc.jpg)

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/cv_result_knowledge"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/ll_result_header"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
                android:visibility="gone"
                app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/black_transparent40"
                app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/d12"
                app:cardElevation="@dimen/d1"
                app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"
                app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">
                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/d10"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/d2">



                </RelativeLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Its because you set the background color to black, your Relative Layout has margin set so the black card background is visible in the margin area. Just remove the card background or remove margins, whichever suits you.

```xml
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/cv_result_knowledge"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/ll_result_header"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
                android:visibility="gone"
                app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/black_transparent40" -<REMOVE THIS
                app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/d12"
                app:cardElevation="@dimen/d1"
                app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"
                app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">
                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/d10" -<REMOVE THIS
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/d2">    -<REMOVE THIS
```

Comment: first thanks. For this question, my requirement need set the CardView  BackGroundCoro  with  "#66000000". we need cardView  opacity.  so how to fix it? hope your answer.

Comment: @K.Ming set the background color of the `RelativeLayout` to `#66000000` and **replace margin with padding**. This way you will get your desired color with same spacing as you have now

Comment: @K.Ming or set the card Background to `#66000000` , set the padding to `CardView` instead of `RelativeLayout` and set the background color transparency of `RelativeLayout` to 0

Comment: thanks, I try your method. but it is not perfect.  you can try. this transparent is not my expectation. because i can not look anything behind the cardview. it like cardview self has the background.

Comment: <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:clickable="true"
android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/d12"
app:cardElevation="@dimen/d1"
app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"
app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">
<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="#66000000"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/d2"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/d10"></RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

Comment: @K.Ming chane Relative layout's color to #00000000

Comment: oh, no. my plan is set cardview transparency. for i can see cardview bebind. not set cardview background, set Relative layout's color to #00000000. this can't fix my problem. you can try in android phone of "xiao mi" or "hua wei".

Comment: @K.Ming then why don't you set the cardview color to `#00000000`?

Comment: i set the cardview color to #00000000, then set the relative color to "#6600000", but this is not i need. Do you have QQ or weChat or facebook, I can contact you. send the image for you.